# What's the origin of the term "chaotic topology"?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, terminology

If $X$ is a set, some sources* refer to the topology $\{\emptyset,X \}$ as the *chaotic topology*. (I've also seen it called the *trivial*, *codiscrete*, and *indiscrete* topology.) What is the origin of and motivation for this term?

The term *discrete topology* makes sense to me because the restriction of the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb R$ to a set of discrete points results in the discrete topology. But I can see no such explanation for the term *chaotic topology*.

*
[[1]](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/discrete+and+codiscrete+topology)
[[2]](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F0-387-28387-0_4)
[[3]](https://books.google.com/books?id=nhm9AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=%22chaotic%20topology%22&source=bl&ots=K3MJtod0f3&sig=ACfU3U0vLmVD-IpF6Lt_Bwq7WbBO6DLJxw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiAm4ufpu7mAhVD0FkKHQb2AgUQ6AEwBnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22chaotic%20topology%22&f=false)
[[4]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trivial_topology)

Comment: Specify “some sources”. Online ones? Links?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma see edit.

Comment: Perhaps a motivation was that in such a topology there is no  locality, no way to distinguish  one location (nbhd) from another. But I've never seen this term before. Another term for it is anti-discrete. I like "indiscrete", but  only because of its non-mathematical social nuances in English.

Comment: It seems that there is some connection to algebraic geometry (perhaps you should add the tag). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_topology. Also see  M. Artin, A. Grothendieck, J-L. Verdier, eds. (1972), SGA4, LNM 269-270-305, Berlin; New York:  Springer-Verlag: Exposé IV, 2.6 . I found this reference in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.4527.pdf.

Comment: @PaulFrost thanks, tag added. That wiki also states that the term *chaotic* is synonymous with *discrete*, which is the opposite of most other sources. If this is not a simple mistake, it adds yet another layer...

Comment: The nlab source links a PDF which it claims motivates the term chaotic topology, though I didn't open it up.

Comment: A more apt name would be the useless topology imo

Comment: @WillG: With Grothendieck topology, chaotic indeed means discrete. Personally, I would never use this terminology.

Comment: The lecturer of the first topology course i ever took used the word chaotic for the indiscrete topology and said this comes from a bible quote: something along the lines of "at the beginning the world was chaotic and empty". Not sure whether that is true but that is at least what he said.

Comment: @ThorWittich From the New International Version of the Bible (Genesis 1:1-2): "In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth. Now the earth was **formless and empty**, darkness was over the surface of the deep, and the Spirit of God was hovering over the waters." See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_1:2.  The orginal Hebrew phrase is "**tohu wabohu**" which some people freely translate by "chaos". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_(cosmogony)#Greco-Roman_tradition .

Comment: @ThorWittich Sounds reasonable. In fact, a space with the indiscrete topology does not satisfy any separation properties. Now the next two verses of Genesis say "And God said, “Let there be light,” and there was light. God saw that the light was good, and he **separated** the light from the darkness."

Comment: The first thing that came to mind is that, when $X$ is a "chaotic" dynamical system, the topology obtained when quotienting by the flow is indiscrete. E.g. when $X$ is a topological space with a continuous group action on it, and the system is chaotic in the sense that all orbits are dense.

Comment: I think that this is the only topology where any sequence/net converges to any point in the space.... There is no more chaos than that.

Comment: The first occurence that I could find is in fact in "Séminaire de Géométrie Algébrique du Bois Marie (SGA)". More pecisely in "SGA4 Théorie des topos et cohomologie étale des schémas, 1963–1964 (Topos theory and étale cohomology), Lecture Notes in Mathematics 269, 270 and 305, 1972/3". See http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/~laszlo/sga4/SGA4-1/sga41.pdf , p.126 : Il existe une topologie moins fine que toute topologie sur $C$; la topologie pour
laquelle $J(X) = \{X\}$ pour tout $X$ de $C$. Cette topologie est appelée la topologie *grossière* ou *chaotique*."

Comment: I also found "Compléments de topologie" by Pierre-Jean Hormière (see https://lescoursdemathsdepjh.monsite-orange.fr/file/122673eabceaa5af4ef38fd7374b9cf8.pdf). In "7.3. Topologie grossière ou chaotique" one finds "Toute suite $(x_n)$ d’un espace chaotique converge vers tout point de $X$, idem pour une suite généralisée, un filtre." This supports N.S.

Comment: It is also interesting to compare wikipedia articles in various languages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology, https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologie_grossi%C3%A8re, https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triviale_Topologie . Surprisingly only the German variant mentions the phrase.

Comment: With the trivial topology, _every net_ converges to _every point_ (ditto for filters). In short, everything converges to everything. So in terms of convergence, the trivial topology is pretty chaotic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the original motivation: When $\leq$ is a partial order on a set $S$, it induces a topology called the *order topology*, which is the one generated by the open rays $\{ c \in S : c < a \}, \{ c \in S : c > a \}$.
The order topology is chaotic precisely if the order is trivial, i.e. if every element is comparable only with itself.

This may explain "chaotic", as the antonym of "ordered".

It seems that a similar point of view was already taken by Felix Hausdorff in [*Grundzüge der Mengenlehre*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundz%C3%BCge_der_Mengenlehre) (1922). He talks about ordered sets in chapters 4–6, and in chapter 7 introduces a notion of a topological space. The introduction to chapter 7 (pp. 209–211) views an order as an example to give additional structure to a set, and goes on to explore generalizations of the concept of an order, and arrives at the notion of neighborhood. Hausdorff remarks that an order can be defined from a suitable system of neighborhoods:

> *Hier wird also eine Menge $M$ unter dem Gesichtspunkt einer Zuordnung zwischen Elementen und Teilmengen betrachtet; wir haben übrigens gezeigt (Kap. IV, § 1), daß man auch die Ordnung einer Menge durch ein passendes System von Teilmengen definieren kann.*

I do not know who first used the word chaotic (or French chaotique, German chaotisch) in the context of topology. It does not appear in Hausdorff's book.

Comment: In fact it would be interesting to know **who** first introduced the phrase.

Comment: Earliest reference I could find was Dieudonne's Foundations of Modern Analysis Chapter XII